# Javascript - instantiate a new filetype from a file in the assets folder

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to upload a photo (png) located locally on my assets folder to Firebase (DaaS). Now as stated in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) i need to make a new Filetype for it. 
[image]

But how would I set such a filetype for my local img? The path of the image is this:

```
../../../../assets/no-photo-avatar.png
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

### Edit

I managed to create a reference to the file with this:

```
const defaultPhoto: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
defaultPhoto.src = '../../../../assets/no_photo_avatar.png';
```

But now I need to convert it it to a `new File()` or `new Blob()` type.

Comment: I think you mean `instantiate` and also you need to create the appropriate reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the image type to a filetype I did this - full solution:

```
  upload(): Promise<void> {
     const defaultPhoto: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
     defaultPhoto.src = '../../../../assets/no_photo_avatar.png';
     return srcToFIle(defaultPhoto.src, defaultPhoto.name, 'image/png').then() => ...) <= firebase methods
  }

  private srcToFile(src, fileName, mimeType): Promise<File> {
     return (fetch(src)
    .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
    .then(buf => new File([buf], fileName, {type: mimeType})));
```

}

btw. the typings are typescript syntax.